# Sequelize error - "model.get is not a function"

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have created a basic CRUD web application using graphql/sequelize/postgres/react.  The following code is in a sequelize resolver in my api, and calling it via graphql query from my react.js frontend yields the error ".get is not a function":

```
let profile = await Profile.find({where: { userId: args.userId }})
profile = await Profile.update(args, {where: { userId: args.userId }})
return profile.get({ plain: true })
```

If I add an additional object.find to the resolver function between the calls to object.update and object.get, I no longer get the error:

```
let profile = await Profile.find({where: { userId: args.userId }})
profile = await Profile.update(args, {where: { userId: args.userId }})
profile = await Profile.find({where: { userId: args.userId }})
return profile.get({ plain: true })
```

Why am I getting this error, and how can I eliminate it without adding the additional call to object.find?

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was not good.

If you're trying to update and return a plane jane object, use this:

```
let profile = await Profile.findById(args.userId);
await profile.update(args);
return profile.toJSON();
```

the "get" method returns a field value, not sure that's what you're wanting to do.

From docs:

```
instance.field
// is the same as
instance.get('field')
// is the same as
instance.getDataValue('field')
```